# Why is the k3s Traefik Ingress returning 404 instead of the service

Tags: raspberry-pi, k3s

Based on the example I created a service with the following...

```
*Index.html*
<html>
<head><title>Hello World!</title>
  <style>
    html {
      font-size: 500.0%;
    }
    div {
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div>Hello World!</div>
</body>
</html>

*Run Command*
k create configmap test-html --from-file index.html

*service.yml*
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "traefik"
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: nginx-service
            port:
              number: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-service
  labels:
    run: nginx
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 80
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app:  nginx
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  replicas: 10
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
        - name: html-volume
          mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html
      volumes:
      - name: html-volume
        configMap:
          name: test-html
```

Everything seems to work just fine from a deployment but when I try to reach `http://<myexternalip>` I get a 404. What am I missing why wouldn't the ingress work?

Answer (score 0):

I had problems with the k3s ingress, but fixed it by removing the ingressClassName value from my kind: Ingress definition, so it picked up the default - see https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#default-ingress-class